# How to group by with two field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need to group by categorycode and categoryname and other fields to add with object.
Sample data:

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":A
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":B
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":B
   }
]
```

though Javascript I need to expected output :

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":[A,B]
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":[B]
   }
]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What are your initial thoughts. If you really want to learn you should give it a try and please add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with reduce.

```js
const arr = [{
    "categoryCode": "categoryCode1",
    "categoryName": "categoryName1",
    "cat_type": "A"
  },
  {
    "categoryCode": "categoryCode1",
    "categoryName": "categoryName1",
    "cat_type": "B"
  },
  {
    "categoryCode": "categoryCode2",
    "categoryName": "categoryName2",
    "cat_type": "B"
  }
]

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((a, {
    categoryCode,
    categoryName,
    cat_type
  }) => (((a[`code_${categoryCode}_name_${categoryName}`] ??= {
    categoryCode,
    categoryName,
    cat_type: []
  }).cat_type.push(cat_type)), a), {})
);
console.log(result)
```